# Elements intermittently not identifying after selecting Spinner value

Tags: java, mobile, automation, android-emulator, appium

I have multiple spinner widgets in a page. After i select the value of one of the spinner element, the next spinner element doesn't get identified intermittently during run-time. Basically Appium identifies the elements in some runs and doesn't identify the elements in other. There is no consistency to this behavior.

I have tried adding implicit waits and thread.sleeps. But no luck. Is there some specific way I need to handle Spinner elements? I am new to Appium.

Comment: What is the exception your are facing? In case if it is throwing stale element exception, you might want to find your element again before performing any actions on it.

Comment: I am getting the "An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters." error eventhough object is right there.

Comment: @PRERNAPAL forgot to tag you in the comment

Comment: Possibly the xpath is intermittently changing after selecting the first spinner. It might be working at times when you are able to find the spinner before the DOM gets updated. Whereas in other case if DOM is already updated, even the explicit wait would not be of help as the element really does not exist on the page. Could you check please? Also, it would be helpful to understand better if you can copy the HTML here (both before and after selecting the first spinner)

Comment: @PRERNAPAL How do i check if the DOM is getting updated or not(i am pretty new to appium)? when i use uiautomatorviewer, I have to restart the emulator to find elements after selecting a spinner value. So every time i have to select a spinner value and identify the new elements, i need to restart the emulator. Could it be that this is the same issue during run-time as well?